# VSFTP user login & activity monitoring

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, vsftpd, deleted-files

We have a linux box that is configured with vsftp for our ftp sessions. Unfortunately, for the last few days, we've found that files served by vsftpd have been lost (deleted).

I would like to know:

1. Who deleted them
2. When deletion occurred
3. How the user logged in

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/vsftpd.log`?

Comment: i have checked vsftpd.log & audit.log but couldn't understand it. as i said i am new.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and change below config:

   ```
   xferlog_enable=YES
   ```
2. After changing the configuration value, open the log file with `tail`:

   ```
   tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log
   ```